# How to add where clause to custom Drupal view

Tags: views

I am fetching data from two table to my view using View API. How can I add where clause to my view?

My actual SQL query is like:

```
select field1,field2,field3,t2field4 from table1,table2 where t2field=field1
```

I come across hook_view_alter() but I dont know how to implement that.
Can I use any filter handler in my views.inc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `hook_view_query_alter()` to add where condition.

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
    $query->add_where(1,'node.nid',$value,'=');  
  }
}
```

Comment: can u elaborate parameter you are passing in add_where function...can i add table_name.field_name in place of $value variable..i am implementing this hook_view_query_alter in "views.inc" file

Comment: Yes, you can add it, provided the table_name is already available in the query. Or else you need to add the table to the query. 
For more info, refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959241/drupal-viewsadd-condition-in-where-clause-where-the-value-is-a-field-in-hook-al

Comment: function kfd_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
 
      if ($view->name == 'report1') {
      $query->add_where(1,'kfd_survey_master_survey_id','kfd_other_works_form_id','=');  
  }
  
} i am adding this code right after defining hook_view_data..but its showing whole table...where contition does not showing any effect.

Comment: Try to put dpm($query) after $query->add_where(1,'kfd_survey_master_survey_id','kfd_other_works_form_id','=')‌​;,

And check if your table is present in table_queue[] and if your where condition is present in where[]. You will get better idea. 

FYI, it doesn't matter if it is after hook_view_data or not.